# Dhcrelay init.d script runs improperly

Tags: linux, centos5, init.d, dhcp

I am trying to use dhcrealy on a CentOs 5 kernel which have kernel version 3.5.3.

I configured /etc/sysconfig/dhcrelay file like that

```
dhcrelay -i eth1 192.168.0.1
```

While dhcrealy is stopped, I run `/etc/init.d/dhcrelay status` and I get this output.

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Relay Agent V3.0.5-RedHat
Copyright 2004-2006 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit http://www.isc.org/sw/dhcp/
Listening on LPF/eth1/08:00:27:49:5e:e7
Sending on   LPF/eth1/08:00:27:49:5e:e7
Sending on   Socket/fallback
dhcrelay (pid 27536) is running...
```

Then I check `ps aux | grep dhcrelay` and see that dhcrelay was started. Although It returns OK, I could not stop it by calling `/etc/init.d/dhcrelay stop` and whenever I check status It starts new proccess. Then I can only stop it by calling `killall dhcrelay` command

My installed dhcp package is dhcp-3.0.5-23.el5_6.4

I wonder is there anybody faced with same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the reason of this error. Conf file should not contain commands. 
I change it as like that and problem solved.

```
INTERFACES="eth1"
DHCPSERVERS="192.168.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely this is simply a broken `init.d`-script, that does not honor the arguments (`start`, `stop`, `status`), but *always* starts the dhcprelay.

you might want to report that as a bug with the maintainers of the package.